# What's wrong with my camlQuery?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, caml-query

Is there something wrong with this query?

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Eenheid\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>" + myUnit + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Volgnr\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');
```

I like to get the last record from my list where the value of "Eenheid" is myUnit. Orderedby Volgnr.

Comment: what's the issue ? Query seems to be fine

Comment: It's not returning anything. When I change to my old query it does: camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Volgnr\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below code. I have changed double quotes in your provided code:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Eenheid\'/><Value Type=\'Text\'>" + myUnit + "</Value></Eq></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Volgnr\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>1</RowLimit></View>");
```